# Python pandas, substitute all elements in a dataframe column with closest string match from known list

Tags: python, pandas, difflib

I have a dataframe where the values in a column are strings which are often mispelled, something like:

```
col01 | col02 | name
-----------------------
 ---  |  ---  |  mrk 
 ---  |  ---  |  anth3n7 
 ---  |  ---  |  j4ck
```

and a list of possible correct values for this column

```
possible_names = ['mark', 'anthony', 'jack']
```

I wanted to go over the elements of the 'name' column, and get the closest match from the list of correct names, so that I would end up with:

```
col01 | col02 | name      |   correct_name
-----------------------------------------
 ---  |  ---  |  mrk      |       mark
 ---  |  ---  |  anth3n7  |      anthony
 ---  |  ---  |  j4ck     |       jack
```

I tried using this code:

```
df_names = pd.read_csv('names/wrong.csv')
possible_names = ['mark', 'anthony', 'jack']
df_names['correct_name'] = difflib.get_close_matches(df_names['name'], possible_names)
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import difflib

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["mrk", "anth3n7", "j4ck"], columns=["name"])
possible_names = ['mark', 'anthony', 'jack']

df["correct_name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, possible_names)[0])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      name correct_name
0      mrk         mark
1  anth3n7      anthony
2     j4ck         jack
```

As an alternative instead of [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), you could use a list comprehension:

```
df["correct_name"] = [difflib.get_close_matches(name, possible_names)[0] for name in df["name"]]
```

**UPDATE**

For the case of no match, one approach is to use:

```
possible_names = ['anthony', 'jack']
df["correct_name"] = [next(iter(difflib.get_close_matches(name, possible_names)), name) for name in df["name"]]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      name correct_name
0      mrk          mrk
1  anth3n7      anthony
2     j4ck         jack
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any way to account for cases where there's no match? I'm getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range", I assume it's because of that.

Comment: @Carlo What output do you think is best in that case? None? The empty string?

Comment: Possibly, I'd leave the original value

Comment: I'm trying to add some if condition in the list comprehension solution you suggested, but I'm probably messing something

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df['new']=df.Name.apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, possible_names, limit=1)][0][0][0])
```